# Issue with copying Files in to the ubuntu server

Tags: server

I’m running Ubuntu server 22.04.3. I have an issue with my server while I’m trying to copy lots of files in to it. It’s start copying but half way through stops and changing disk privilege to read only file system. Ssd formatted as ext4. All privileges as set to 777. Even I tried copy as guest or with user all this same. Changed ownership to nobody:nobody group but that not resolve this problem. Switched swap usage to minimum so files goes strait in to the disk setting swappinness to 1. Even tried while copying files switch off swap but that doesn’t help is well. After when system change disk to read only file system when trying to reboot system it’s freezing even when I kill all the processes. I had to reboot the machine by the button so it’s goes back to normal mode. Maybe anyone have solution for this issue. Thank you for your help. Regards Sam.

Comment: Sounds like broken hardware (harddisk).

Comment: You should check system log at the time the problem occurs.

Comment: Ssd was brand new Kingston 1T. I have swap Ssd to my old HDD 500g Seagate and all works fine so it’s looks like software have an issue with this Ssd drive.

Comment: Flash media (which includes SSDs) being remounted as read-only is typically a sign of hardware failure. I've seen that countless times with SD or micro SD cards. Flash media have a limited number of write cycles, and when you use them heavily, they will wear out, despite built-in wear leveling.

Comment: Thanks for all answers.